# ASP.NET MVC + Checkbox como proceder?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, checkbox, framework

tenho uma lista onde Cadastro TIMES DE FUTEBOL em CAMPEONATOS, ou seja, preciso selecionar vários times para um campeonato, eu faço uma lista com os checkbox mas não sei como proceder depois:

```
<ul>
                   @foreach (var item in ((List<TCC.Models.time>)ViewData["listTime"]))
                   {
                       foreach (var item2 in ((List<TCC.Models.participante_campeonato>)ViewData["listParticipante"]))
                       {
                           if (item.id_time == item2.id_time) {
                                <label class="col-md-12"><li class="task-normal ui-tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Time Alocado"> <input type="checkbox" checked> <span>@item.nome_time</span> </li></label>
                           } else {
                            <label class="col-md-12"><li class="task-important"> <input type="checkbox"> <span>@item.nome_time</span> </li></label>
                           }
                       }
                   }
                </ul>
```

quando o administrador acessa a página de campeonatos abaixo mostra os times que estão alocados conforme o código acima, e uma opção para atualizar caso um time esteja ou não esteja no campeonato, como posso fazer isto? o que mandar para o controller?

Vamos supor, tem 2 times marcados, e quero marcar mais 2 times, como eu faria isto?

Outra situação tem 2 times marcados, e quero desmacar os mesmos, como eu faria isto?

OBS:
Tenho uma tabela chamada alocar_campeonato, onde eu aloco o id do campeonato, e o id do time para validar q o time está no campeonato.

Estou utilizado asp.net MVC + entity framework